# How to make foreign key using gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have those two models:

User model:

```
type User struct {
    DBBase
    Email    string `gorm:"column:email" json:"email"`
    Password string `gorm:"column:password" json:"-"`
}

func (User) TableName() string {
    return "t_user"
}
```

User info model:

```
type UserInfo struct {
    User      User   `gorm:"foreignkey:u_id;association_foreignkey:id"`
    UID       uint   `gorm:"column:u_id" json:"-"`
    FirstName string `gorm:"column:first_name" json:"first_name"`
    LastName  string `gorm:"column:last_name" json:"last_name"`
    Phone     string `gorm:"column:phone" json:"phone"`
    Address   string `gorm:"column:address" json:"address"`
}

func (UserInfo) TableName() string {
    return "t_user_info"
}
```

and I want to make UID related to the id of the user table.

this is the function that creates the user:

```
func (dao *AuthDAO) Register(rs app.RequestScope, user *models.User, userInfo *models.UserInfo) (userErr error, userInfoErr error) {
    createUser := rs.Db().Create(&user)
    userInfo.UID = user.ID
    createUserInfo := rs.Db().Create(&userInfo)

    return createUser.Error, createUserInfo.Error
}
```

I did try what gorm wrote on the documentation, but without success:
http://doc.gorm.io/associations.html

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Devon the "Belongs To" section

Comment: Yeah... what in that section?  You didn't include any relationship in your above code.

Comment: @Devon, sorry, you right. I edited the code. thanks.

Comment: The foreignkey should be UID, the association foreign key shouldn't be needed if it's id.

Comment: @Devon this is not working also

Comment: So you have `gorm:"foreignkey:UID"`?  How are you trying to retrieve the relationship? Any errors?

Comment: @Devon edited the question with the creation function. I don't have any errors. the user created but UID isn't a foreign key (i can change it to any id i wants without any error)

Comment: So you're concerned about the missing index/fk in the schema, not about the ability to pull the related model?  Are you migrating with gorm?  You need to consult http://doc.gorm.io/database.html#migration

Comment: @Devon yes, am do a migration.

Comment: you can try db.Exec("....") for create foreign key

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Note!**
>
> from gorm 2.0 this is no longer necessary, read more here:
> [gorm.io/docs/belongs_to.html#FOREIGN-KEY-Constraints](https://gorm.io/docs/belongs_to.html#FOREIGN-KEY-Constraints)

The solution is to add this line when migrating the database:

```
db.Model(&models.UserInfo{}).AddForeignKey("u_id", "t_user(id)", "RESTRICT", "RESTRICT")
```

[migration (gorm documentation)](http://gorm.io/docs/migration.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response !

Comment: As of gorm 2.0 this is no longer necessary. Follow https://gorm.io/docs/belongs_to.html#FOREIGN-KEY-Constraints

Comment: @jnnnnn what if I can't add gorm tags to fields as my models are auto-generated from graphql schema using gqlgen? I can no longer add relations via code?

Answer (score 3):

I found the following code correctly created the foreign key without having to do any custom migration code; just the usual `AutoMigrate`.

```golang
type Account struct {
    ID uint `gorm:"primary_key"`
}

type Transaction struct {
    ID        uint `gorm:"primary_key"`
    AccountID uint
    Account   Account `gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
}
```

I am using "Gorm 2.0" which is a dependency of `gorm.io/gorm v1.23.3`.

Answer (score 1):

For recent release of Gorm i.e. `1.21.x`If you have a one to one mapping of fields and not have parent to child mapping, here is what you will do

```
type BaseConfig struct {
    ID         uuid.UUID       `gorm:"primary_key" json:"id"`
}

type Ledger struct { 
    BaseConfigId        uuid.UUID       `json:"base_config_id"`
    BaseConfig BaseConfig               `gorm:"column:base_config_id;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:SET NULL;"`

}
```

In Migration script you will need to follow as per [docs](https://gorm.io/docs/migration.html#Constraints)

```
WriteClient.Migrator().CreateConstraint(&models.BaseConfig{}, "Ledgers")
WriteClient.Migrator().CreateConstraint(&models.BaseConfig{}, "fk_base_configs_id")
```

I feel the tripping point is the missing documentation for how to associate. Some juggling around could be there to figure it out, so hope my answer saves some time.

Answer (score 1):

In our case we needed full flexibility in terms of column/field names, as we were migrating an existing database originally made by SQLAlchemy. Not using the names that Gorm expects results in foreign keys not being made.

Using Gorm 2.0 which for some reason still has v1 tags (`gorm.io/gorm v1.25.1`), the trick is to use `foreignkey` (must point to the local field) and `references` (most point to the remote field in the foreign table) annotations correctly for totally arbitrary names:

```
type Other struct {
    OtherId int32 `gorm:"primarykey; column:custom_col_other_id"`
}

type Main struct {
    MainId    int32 `gorm:"primarykey; column:custom_col_main_id"`
    FkOtherId int32 `gorm:"column:custom_col_fk_other_id"`
    OtherRef  Other `gorm:"foreignkey:FkOtherId;references:OtherId"`
}

...

dbClient.AutoMigrate(&Other{})
dbClient.AutoMigrate(&Main{})
```

This results in the correct foreign key relation:

```
                                        Table "public.others"
       Column        |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |                       Default                       
---------------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------
 custom_col_other_id | integer |           | not null | nextval('others_custom_col_other_id_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
    "others_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (custom_col_other_id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "mains" CONSTRAINT "fk_mains_other_ref" FOREIGN KEY (custom_col_fk_other_id) REFERENCES others(custom_col_other_id)"

                                            Table "public.mains"
         Column         |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |                      Default                      
------------------------+---------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------------------
 custom_col_main_id     | integer |           | not null | nextval('mains_custom_col_main_id_seq'::regclass)
 custom_col_fk_other_id | integer |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "mains_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (custom_col_main_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_mains_other_ref" FOREIGN KEY (custom_col_fk_other_id) REFERENCES others(custom_col_other_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about the belongs to relationship in https://gorm.io/docs/belongs_to.html
Also, there's a good example here: https://medium.com/@the.hasham.ali/how-to-use-uuid-key-type-with-gorm-cc00d4ec7100

```
// User is the model for the user table.
type User struct {
 Base
 SomeFlag bool    `gorm:"column:some_flag;not null;default:true"`
 Profile  Profile
}// Profile is the model for the profile table.
type Profile struct {
 Base
 Name   string    `gorm:"column:name;size:128;not null;"`
 UserID uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;column:user_foreign_key;not null;"`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can add foreign key constraints in the latest version using `CreateConstraint`.

**Example**:
Suppose we have two entity

```
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  CreditCards []CreditCard
}

type CreditCard struct {
  gorm.Model
  Number string
  UserID uint
}
```

Now create database foreign key for user & credit_cards

```
db.Migrator().CreateConstraint(&User{}, "CreditCards")
db.Migrator().CreateConstraint(&User{}, "fk_users_credit_cards")
```

which translates to the following SQL code for Postgres:

```
ALTER TABLE `credit_cards` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_users_credit_cards` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users`(`id`)
```

Referrence:

- [Gorm official doc for Constraint Creation](https://gorm.io/docs/migration.html#Constraints)
- [Changes in the latest version](https://gorm.io/docs/v2_release_note.html#Foreign-Keys)