# gorm, foreign keys, and embedded structs

Tags: go, foreign-keys, go-gorm

Gorm's half-baked, magic-out-the-box support of foreign keys has been an annoyance for years and I'm finally trying to figure it out once and for all. I'm using Postgres 12, gorm 1.23.3 and go 1.18.

I have a base model similar to `gorm.Model` but with a little bit extra:

```
type BaseModel struct {
    ID              string          `json:"id" gorm:"type:uuid;primarykey;default:uuid_generate_v4()"`
    InstanceVersion int             `json:"instanceVersion"`
    CreatedAt       time.Time       `json:"createdAt" gorm:"type:timestamp"`
    UpdatedAt       time.Time       `json:"updatedAt" gorm:"type:timestamp"`
    DeletedAt       *time.Time      `json:"deletedAt,omitempty" gorm:"type:timestamp" sql:"index"`
    CreatedBy       string          `json:"createdBy"`
    UpdatedBy       string          `json:"updatedBy"`
    DeletedBy       string          `json:"deletedBy,omitempty"`
    MetaData        json.RawMessage `json:"metadata" gorm:"type:jsonb;default:'{}'"`
}
```

Every model in my DB uses this `BaseModel` as follows:

```
type Profile struct {
    BaseModel

    Name   string `json:"name"`
    UserID string `json:"userId"`
}
```

It generates the tables as follows (UML generated by DBeaver and double checked to be true):

[image: UML Diagram]

I'm trying to add a foreign key to the `CreatedBy` and `UpdatedBy` columns such that they must point to an existing `Profile`. So I add the following field to the `BaseModel` type:

```
    CreatedByProfile *Profile `json:"-" gorm:"foreignKey:CreatedBy"`
```

I expected the foreign key to be created for every model that `BaseModel` is a part of and point back to the `Profiles` table. However, it only makes the FK on the `Profiles` table.

[image: UML Diagram]

Minimal recreation of the problem:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "time"

    "github.com/lib/pq"
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type BaseModel struct {
    ID              string          `json:"id" gorm:"type:uuid;primarykey;default:uuid_generate_v4()"`
    InstanceVersion int             `json:"instanceVersion"`
    CreatedAt       time.Time       `json:"createdAt" gorm:"type:timestamp"`
    UpdatedAt       time.Time       `json:"updatedAt" gorm:"type:timestamp"`
    DeletedAt       *time.Time      `json:"deletedAt,omitempty" gorm:"type:timestamp" sql:"index"`
    CreatedBy       string          `json:"createdBy"`
    UpdatedBy       string          `json:"updatedBy"`
    DeletedBy       *string         `json:"deletedBy,omitempty"`
    MetaData        json.RawMessage `json:"metadata" gorm:"type:jsonb;default:'{}'"`

    CreatedByProfile *Profile `json:"-" gorm:"foreignKey:CreatedBy"`
}

type ActivityType string

type Activity struct {
    Base BaseModel `gorm:"embedded"`

    Type                ActivityType   `json:"type"`
    Message             string         `json:"message"`
    Content             string         `json:"content"`
    ImageUrl            string         `json:"imageUrl"`
    DisplayProfileIds   pq.StringArray `json:"displayProfileIds" gorm:"type:uuid[]"`
    RecipientProfileIds pq.StringArray `json:"recipientProfileIds" gorm:"-"`

    // Preload
    ActivityProfiles []*ActivityProfile `json:"activityProfiles"` // has many
}

type ActivityProfile struct {
    Base BaseModel `gorm:"embedded"`

    ReadAt *time.Time `json:"readAt,omitempty" gorm:"type:timestamp" sql:"index"`
    Route  string     `json:"route"`

    ActivityID string `json:"activityId"`
    ProfileID  string `json:"profileId"`

    // Preload
    Activity *Activity `json:"activity"` // belongs to
    Profile  *Profile  `json:"profile"`  // belongs to
}

type Profile struct {
    BaseModel

    Name   string `json:"name"`
    UserID string `json:"userId"`
}

func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open("host=localhost port=5432 user=corey dbname=corey password= sslmode=disable"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    models := []interface{}{
        &Activity{},
        &ActivityProfile{},
        &Profile{},
    }

    err = db.AutoMigrate(models...)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

I've also tried using `gorm:"embedded"` tags instead of nested structs but it didn't help. Nothing in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53014179/how-to-make-foreign-key-using-gorm) helps: `DB.Model(...).AddForeignKey(...)` doesn't exist anymore, the `db.Migrator().CreateConstraint(...)` lines don't work (how does it know what column is the FK and which column it matches to of what other type? Do I have to run both lines? How could this ever possibly work?!?), and I don't want `OnUpdate` or `OnDelete` constraints, just foreign keys.

If I put the `CreatedByProfile` field on `Activity`, then I get a FK where `Profile.CreatedBy` is an FK to `Activity.ID` which is 100% backwards.

I can add this field to my `Profile` model:

```
Activities []*Activity `json:"-" gorm:"foreignKey:CreatedBy"`
```

and it creates the FK like I want, but I don't actually want that field present on the model. Plus, I'd have to add this unnecessary boilerplate for every model in my DB (and `_` fields don't end up with the FK being made).

How can I make Gorm do simple things like create foreign keys without decorating my models with unused fields?

Comment: I did discover that you can reliably create FKs by hacking the gorm tag: `gorm:"type:uuid REFERENCES profiles(id)"`. It works by hijacking the query. Gorm thinks the type is `uuid REFERENCES profiles(id)` but postgres sees it as an FK definition. This will work for simpler DB designs, but ours has circular references which means all the tables have to be created before any of the FKs can be. I'm probably going to remove gorm from the FK equation and just run some raw ALTER TABLE queries after AutoMigrate because gorm doesn't seem to care about actually good DB design.

Comment: I decided to just decorate my structs with `gorm` tags that don't add FKs, I pass `&gorm.Config{ DisableForeignKeyConstraintWhenMigrating: true }` to `gorm.Open(...)`, and I wrote `db.Exec(...)` lines that'll add the FKs. Gorm is a decent ORM, but an awful migrator.